# Other than beer are there any fictional drinks that eventually became real?

Tags: history, drink

While reading this question ([What other beer brands began as fictional but eventually became real?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/what-other-beer-brands-began-as-fictional-but-eventually-became-real/3516)), I became interested in knowing if there are any fictional alcoholic drinks other than beer that eventually became real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The world of Harry Potter has spawned an entire universe of beverages, both with and without alcohol, including those served at Universal Studios theme parks, and many independently-inspired creations.

Eater Miami describes [Everything You Need to Eat and Drink at The Wizarding World of Harry Potter](https://miami.eater.com/2016/5/27/11697900/harry-potter-wizarding-world-orlando-florida-butterbeer) by Olee Fowler (May 27, 2016) (emphasis added).

> **Non-Alcoholic**: Just as the food remains true to the books and the setting, so do the drinks. The real star of the area is the famous Butterbeer and can be found roughly every 20 feet inside both parks. **Butterbeer** is a butterscotch meets caramel meets cream soda flavored drink. It’s offered in regular form, frozen and even hot for the few days out of the year it drops below 70 degrees.
>
> Almost as popular as the butterbeer is the **Pumpkin Juice**, which is combination of pineapple and apple juices mixed with pumpkin spice flavoring, and tastes like fall in a cup. Diagon Alley also features the almost neon-bright **Fishy Green Ale**, which is a mash up of mint and cinnamon with blueberry flavored pearls akin to boba at the bottom. Then there is the twist on lemonade called **Tongue Tying Lemon Squash**, a fizzy orange concoction known as the **Otter’s Fizzy Juice** and the **Peachtree Fizzing Tea**, an unsweetened ice tea.
>
> **Alcoholic**: But we know what you’re really thinking — what about the booze? Unlike its theme park counterpart Disney World down the street, all Universal parks allow alcohol on-site. Both Hogsmeade and Diagon Alley serve two **proprietary beers**: the dark, malt-heavy porter known as **Wizard’s Brew** and the lighter lager-style **Dragon Scale beer**, both created by the Florida Beer Brewing Company.
>
> Adjacent to Three Broomsticks is Hog’s Head Pub is the only bar in the two worlds, which is a bit grim and dark in keeping with the theme of the books. The highlight of the menu is the pub’s own **Fire Whiskey**, which is its take on cinnamon-flavored Fireball. It also happens to pair well with the Butterbeer. No sodas can be found in Hog’s Head, but there are a few specialty drinks like **Hog’s Tea**, a Long Island iced tea riff and the strongest drink on the menu, and the **Pear Dazzle**, which is a mix of vodka and pear cider.

And a recipe sampling from the BuzzFeed article on [8 Magical And Delicious Harry Potter Cocktails](https://www.buzzfeed.com/rachelysanders/harry-potter-and-the-night-he-wont-remember?utm_term=.ryzk5eb9Nm#.dr2Ep12qVw)

> **Unicorn Blood**
>   1.5 oz silver tequila
>   1.5 oz St. Germain (elderflower liqueur)
>   1 oz lemon juice
>
> Add everything to a cocktail shaker with ice and shake (hard!) for a full 20 seconds. Strain into a coupe glass. Serves 1.
>
> **Hair Of The Three-Headed Dog**
>   1.5 oz tequila
>   1/2 cup tomato juice
>   1 tablespoon lime juice
>   1 tablespoon Worcestershire sauce
>   1 teaspoon Tabasco
>   1 12-oz bottle Mexican beer (like Corona or Modelo)
>   2 tablespoons kosher salt 
>   1/2 teaspoon chili powder
>   1 celery stalk, washed, root end trimmed (optional)
>
> Mix tequila, tomato juice, lime juice, Worcestershire and Tabasco sauces. Mix salt and chili powder together in a small bowl or saucer. Rub the rim of a pint glass with a slice of lime and roll the outside of the glass rim in the chili salt to coat it. Fill glass halfway with ice, add tomato mixture, stir well, and top with beer. Garnish with celery if you like. Serves 1.
>
> **Wolfsbane Potion**
>   1.5 oz Scotch whiskey
>   1.5 oz Fernet-Branca
>   Coca-Cola
>
> Combine Scott and Fernet in a shaker with ice and stir vigorously for 20 seconds, until fully chilled. Strain into a rocks glass with a large ice cube. Top with cola, to taste. Serves 1.
>
> **The Phoenix Feather**
>   2 oz Lillet Blanc
>   1.5 oz Campari
>   1 oz fresh-squeezed grapefruit juice
>   seltzer or club soda
>
> Combine Lillet, Campari, and grapefruit juice in a cocktail shaker with ice and shake, vigorously, for about 20 seconds. Strain into a Collins glass filled with ice cubes and top with seltzer. Serves 1.
>
> **Butterbeer**
>   6-8 tablespoons butterscotch sauce (depending how sweet you like it)
>   3 cups apple cider
>   1 cup bourbon whiskey (optional)
>   2 cups ginger beer
>   Whipped cream, for garnish
>
> Heat cider, bourbon and butterscotch syrup in a medium saucepan until the butterscotch dissolves and the mixture is steaming hot. Remove from heat and stir in the ginger beer. Ladle into mugs and serve with loads of whipped cream on top. Serves 6-8.
>
> **Polyjuice Potion**
>   1.5 oz gin
>   1.5 oz fresh-pressed or bottled green juice
>   1 oz green Chartreuse
>   ½ oz lime juice
>   7-Up or Sprite (optional)
>
> Shake gin, juices, and Chartreuse in a shaker with ice. Strain into a glass (you can serve up or over ice) and top with a splash of soda if you'd like it a little lighter. Serves 1.
>
> **Felix Felicis ("Liquid Luck")**
>   1/4 oz simple syrup
>   1/4 oz lemon juice
>   1.5 oz ginger beer
>   Champagne or other sparkling wine
>
> Mix simple syrup and lemon juice in the bottom of a champagne flute. Add ginger beer and fill with Champagne. Serves 1.
>
> **Amortentia Love Potion Punch**
>   For ice ring:
>   1 pint fresh red raspberries
>   1 cup fresh pomegranate seeds
>   4 cups water, boiled and cooled
>   ice cubes
>   For punch:
>   1 750-ml bottle Aperol
>   4 cups pomegranate juice
>   2 cups gin
>   2 750-ml bottles chilled rosé sparkling wine
>
> Spread raspberries and pomegranate seeds in the bottom of a bundt or ring cake pan. Cover fruit with a layer of ice cubes to keep it in place and pour enough boiled water over to just cover the ice (you don't need to use all the water). Freeze overnight. Mix Aperol, pomegranate juice, and gin together in a large punch bowl. When you're ready to serve the punch, add sparkling wine and stir gently. Float the ice ring on top. Serves about 20.

Answer (score 2):

The [Vesper Martini](http://www.jamesbondlifestyle.com/product/vesper-martini) was first described by James Bond in Ian Fleming's book Casino Royale in 1953. The recipe is:

> "Three measures of Gordon's, one of vodka, half a measure of Kina
>   Lillet. Shake it very well until it's ice-cold, then add a large thin
>   slice of lemon-peel."

Answer (score 1):

[Star Trek Saurian Brandy](https://www.epicurus.com/beverages/saurian-brandy/1144/). This is a fake drink, along with Klingon Blood Wine and Romulan Ale, that have been recreated in the real world.

Comment: I like the idea, keep it coming.

Comment: How to make eight fake science fiction drinks. http://www.thegeektwins.com/2012/08/how-to-make-eight-fake-sci-fi-drinks.html My favorite is the Pan Galactic Gargleblaster from Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.